# How to debounce redux action inside of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

So I am trying to debounce some actions inside react component.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";
...

@connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {someAction}
)
class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.debouncedAction = debounce(props.someAction, 300);// someAction works ok
  }

  onSomeEvent = (...args) => {
   this.debouncedAction(args); // this does not work
  }
}
```

So the modified `debouncedAction` is not called. Is there a way to do that without creating extra action in `mapStateToProps`?
I need to keep both because one for filtering second(debounced) for search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible to debounce the event handler, which then uses the action.

```
class SomeClass extends Component {

  // Debounce the event handler here instead
  onSomeEvent = debounce((...args) => {
    const { someAction } = this.props;
    someAction(...args);
  }, 300)

  // ...
}
```

It also ensures that each time the event callback is executed, it uses the current prop value, so it's always up to date.